# Why numerical optimization does not return better intermediate result?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am using the R package "BB" to maximize a log likelihood function (the objective function). I didn't change any control parameters in BBoptim, besides supplying my objective function and its arguments.

The optimization algorithm successfully converged. However, I can see from the output of "BBoptim" that in the middle of its iterations, it actually find a higher objective function value that its final report.

I think the default algorithm used by "BBoptim" is "spg". I would really appreciate if anyone could point me to the reason of that and maybe a more appropriate setting of "BBoptim" optimization parameters.

Comment: I think the package name is "BB" and function is "BBoptim". Wouldn't you want an optimization algorithm to search widely so that it doesn't falsely stop at local minima? As I read the documentation this was not designed for functions that were known to have nice convergence features. You should read the citations offered in the help page (before posting questions that ask others to do this for you.)

Comment: Hard to answer without a reproducible example ...

Comment: @BenBolker I understand, but the function is a bit complicated and the data size is large. I'll try to find a smaller subset that's reproducible.

Comment: Can you check if the intermediate values of the objective function correspond to feasible solutions (i.e., that all variables fall inside the box constraints)?